# how to style calender on image click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to show Datetime picker on click on image and searching stackoverflow gives me the following answer:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />

  $("#dp").datepicker({
        buttonImage: '../images/icon_star.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'both',
     });
```

But it gives output :first the textbox and then the image button: 
[image]

I need the output as as first the button and then the textbox

[image]

How could I style this?

Comment: Float the image to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with noob. Please see the code here.

https://jsfiddle.net/p5ycaypd/

Add below in css:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    float: left;
}
```

This will work for you.